# Converting PyTorch Code to Keras Code for Neural Net With Nested Layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to recreate NBeats from PyTorch to Keras. I'm working off the source code listed on this page:  https://github.com/ElementAI/N-BEATS/blob/master/models/nbeats.py. Here's the example PyTorch Code I'm trying to emulate:

**PYTORCH CODE:**

```
class NBeatsBlock(t.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 input_size,
                 theta_size: int,
                 basis_function: t.nn.Module,
                 layers: int,
                 layer_size: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = t.nn.ModuleList([t.nn.Linear(in_features=input_size, out_features=layer_size)] +
                                      [t.nn.Linear(in_features=layer_size, out_features=layer_size)
                                       for _ in range(layers - 1)])
        self.basis_parameters = t.nn.Linear(in_features=layer_size, out_features=theta_size)
        self.basis_function = basis_function

    def forward(self, x: t.Tensor) -> Tuple[t.Tensor, t.Tensor]:
        block_input = x
        for layer in self.layers:
            block_input = t.relu(layer(block_input))
        basis_parameters = self.basis_parameters(block_input)
        return self.basis_function(basis_parameters)


class NBeats(t.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, blocks: t.nn.ModuleList):
        super().__init__()
        self.blocks = blocks

    def forward(self, x: t.Tensor, input_mask: t.Tensor) -> t.Tensor:
        residuals = x.flip(dims=(1,))
        input_mask = input_mask.flip(dims=(1,))
        forecast = x[:, -1:]
        for i, block in enumerate(self.blocks):
            backcast, block_forecast = block(residuals)
            residuals = (residuals - backcast) * input_mask
            forecast = forecast + block_forecast
        return forecast

class GenericBasis(t.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, backcast_size: int, forecast_size: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.backcast_size = backcast_size
        self.forecast_size = forecast_size

    def forward(self, theta: t.Tensor):
        return theta[:, :self.backcast_size], theta[:, -self.forecast_size:]
```

This is my Keras implementation of it:

**KERAS CODE:**

```
class NBeatsBlock(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, 
                 theta_size: int,
                 basis_function: keras.layers.Layer,
                 layer_size: int = 4):
        super(NBeatsBlock, self).__init__()
        self.layers_          = [keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation = 'relu') 
                                    for i in range(layer_size)]
        self.basis_parameters = keras.layers.Dense(theta_size)
        self.basis_function   = basis_function
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.layers_[0](inputs)
        for layer in self.layers_[1:]:
            x = layer(x)
        x = self.basis_parameters(x)
        return self.basis_function(x)
    
class NBeats(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, 
                 blocksize: int,
                 theta_size: int,
                 basis_function: keras.layers.Layer):
        super(NBeats, self).__init__()
        self.blocks = [NBeatsBlock(theta_size =  theta_size, basis_function =  basis_function) for i in range(blocksize)]
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        residuals = K.reverse(inputs, axes = 0)
        forecast  = inputs[:, -1:]
        for block in self.blocks:
            backcast, block_forecast = block(residuals)
            residuals                = residuals - backcast
            forecast                 = forecast + block_forecast
        return forecast
    
class GenericBasis(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, backcast_size: int, forecast_size: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.backcast_size = backcast_size
        self.forecast_size = forecast_size
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs[:, :self.backcast_size], inputs[:, -self.forecast_size:]
```

This looks very similar to me, and the keras code allows me to build an actual model with it as well:

```
inputs       = Input(shape = (1, ))

nbeats       = NBeats(blocksize = 4, theta_size = 7, basis_function = GenericBasis(7, 7))(inputs)
out          = keras.layers.Dense(7)(nbeats)

model        = Model(inputs, out)
```

However, it seems like the internal `NBeatsBlock` layers are not there when I check the model summary:

[image]

Similarly, when I plot the model I see no trace of the internal `Dense` layers created inside the `NBeats` block:

[image]

I don't need someone to troubleshoot all of my code, I'm most concerned with why none of the `NBeatsBlock` layers show up in my `NBeats` layer, and I presume this means I'm doing something incorrectly, although I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: Would you mind to response the given answer and giving some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible workaround for printing the model summary but may not be the general solution. First subclass with `tf.keras.Model` class as follows:

```
class NBeatsBlock(tf.keras.Model):
   ...

class NBeats(tf.keras.Model):
   ...

class GenericBasis(tf.keras.Model):
   ...
```

Now, during the print model summary, do as follows

```
NBeats(blocksize = 1 ...)
...
model        = Model(inputs, out)
model.summary(expand_nested=True) < --- TRUE
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_42 (InputLayer)       [(None, 1)]               0         
                                                                 
 NBeats (NBeats)             (None, 7)                 103       
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
| NBeatsBlock (NBeatsBlock)  multiple                 103       |
||¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯||
|| dense_728 (Dense)       multiple                  8         ||
||                                                             ||
|| dense_729 (Dense)       multiple                  20        ||
||                                                             ||
|| dense_730 (Dense)       multiple                  20        ||
||                                                             ||
|| dense_731 (Dense)       multiple                  20        ||
||                                                             ||
|| dense_732 (Dense)       multiple                  35        ||
||                                                             ||
|| generic_basis_45 (GenericBa  multiple             0         ||
|| sis)                                                        ||
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 dense_733 (Dense)           (None, 7)                 56        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 159
Trainable params: 159
Non-trainable params: 0
```

One issue though, output shape of some nested layers isn't shown. Now, `plot_model` is not working either.

```
# output: same as yours - issue remains
utils.plot_model(model,
                 expand_nested=True, show_layer_activations=True)
```

I think, there's no problem in your code that relates to these two functions (`summary` or `plot_model`). It should be that [known issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13782) with the API. And I think you should open an [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3Abug&template=00-bug-template.md) with details.